# Get latitude longitude when WIFiI not available in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, location

I am getting my current location in my application by

```
-   (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

is it works if wifi is not available ? is there any other way for getting my current location GPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will work when there is no WiFi available. 
The `CLLoactionManager` will try to triangulate the location by wifi first, then cell towers and will use GPS as the last option.

This is why the `didUpdateToLocation` get called multiple times, every time the location will get more precieze. When it get a real GPS fix the positron will be the most precieze.

The is no way to see how the `CLLoactionManager`  retrieved the  location, however you can look at the accuracy to see how accurate the location is.

Comment: thanks rckoenes, so  i am using above method with CLLocation manager. so with desiredAccuracy best and not specifying distanceFilter. then it will work for me ?

Comment: Yes, you will keep on receiving locations as the system get a more precies fix of the location.

Comment: and is there any need for startSignificantChangeUpdates?

Comment: The `startSignificantChangeUpdates` will only update the user location when the iOS detect that the user has moves. These will almost always be cell tower based locations.

Comment: thanks dear , means if i write both method startSignificantChangeUpdates and     [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation]; it will work fine in all conditions . wether wifi , gps or tower based locations.

Comment: No, the `startUpdatingLocation` will stop the `startSignificantChangeUpdates`. The `startSignificantChangeUpdates` is meant to be used when you app is receiving location notification in background. Just use `startUpdatingLocation` and stop the location update when you have the desired location accuracy.

Comment: actually i want to use may current location in both cases when app is in background and foreground .

Comment: You should not use `startUpdatingLocation` to musch especialy in the background since it will drain the battery. `startSignificantChangeUpdates` is a better option when you needs to receive location updates in background.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6257/discussion-between-pjr-and-rckoenes)

Comment: but it is not working when i turn off my wifi , is is not getting lat long.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your device and available services, Location Services uses a combination of cellular, Wi-Fi, and GPS to determine your location. If you're not within a clear line of sight to GPS satellites, your device can determine your location using crowd-sourced Wi-Fi3 and cell tower locations.

Please refer - [iOS 5: Understanding Location Services](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4995?viewlocale=en_US)

Or [get location on iphone ONLY from the GPS - not the wifi network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102423/get-location-on-iphone-only-from-the-gps-not-the-wifi-network)

[Does GPS work on iPhone 4 or 3GS without any wi-fi or 3G connection ?](http://applefanatic.org/iphone/does-gps-work-iphone-3gs-without-any-connection-t73005.html)